Amazon Appstore submissions being rejected? How to get more info?
My app's current version has been suppressed by the app store due to the presence of an ad network SDK/Library. Following the suggestion from the Amazon App Store, we removed all ad SDK content from our app and resubmitted it. However, the app was still rejected with the same message instructing us to remove the ad SDK. We're uncertain about what to do next, as we have already removed all SDKs from our app.
We already had this app live for last 2 years, however it got removed.
We have posted on amazon community forum as well but no response from their end. I don't understand what mechanism they're using to test the app.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.incremental": "true"]
            }
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable = true
            resValue("string", "DB_PASSWORD_FIBERTEST_DB", keystoreProperties['dbPassword'])
            resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8082")
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }
        releaseTestAds {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable = false
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
    }

    ndkVersion "21.3.6528147"

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/libs" }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

    //Kotlin Std. lib.
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10"

    //UI
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0" //1.2.0-alpha04

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-installations-ktx'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Google Play Service
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'

    //Logging
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Networking
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.8.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0" //last stable v3.14.7
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0" //last stable v3.11.0
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"

    //Image Loading
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0"

    //Threading
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"


    // Database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"
    implementation "com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.2.1" //SQLite cipher

    // Database debugging
    debugImplementation "com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db-encrypt:1.0.6"

    // Background Work
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0"

    //Google Play Service
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'

    // Messaging Bus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'

    //Loading animation
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
}

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
We have removed everything SDK and Libraries falls in above category.
